# How do I avoid ConcurrentModificationException in ArrayList ONLY when iterating?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

For clarification - I DO NOT want to remove anything from the ArrayList. Therefore 90% of all the answers I have found don't actually apply. I can't find anything here, or elsewhere that helps me out much!

I'm writing a Java Application to play Hangman where the opponent (computer) is essentially cheating, in the sense where it does not 'choose' a word, it has a group of words and decides if the player's guess is correct, or incorrect, depending on which of those leaves the more difficult group of words to guess from.

In a nutshell, my problem is this:

I have an ArrayList, `masterList`, where I have a set of words, a dictionary if you will, and various methods iterate through this to perform various tasks. My code is single threaded and one of these methods is throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` when trying to access the next object in the ArrayList in the second iteration. However, I cannot find anything that actually changes the ArrayList during the iteration.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    private ArrayList<String> masterList;
    private ArrayList<String> contains;
    private ArrayList<String> doesNotContain;
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> wordLengthList;
    private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> difficultyList;
    private int guesses = 10;
    private Scanner sc;
    private FileReader fr;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private String guessString;
    private char guessChar;
    private static final String DICTIONARY = "smalldictionary.txt";
    private String wordLengthString;
    private int wordLengthInt = 0;


    public Main(){

        masterList = new ArrayList<String>();
        contains = new ArrayList<String>();
        doesNotContain= new ArrayList<String>();
        wordLengthList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
        difficultyList = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();

        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        importTestDictionary(); //does not use masterList

        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        importWords(); //Adds to masterList. Both readers closed when finished.

        catalogLengths(); //Iterates through masterList - does not change it.


        do{
            setWordLength(); //does not use masterList
        }while(!(validateLengthInput(wordLengthString))); //validation will change the set of masterList if valid.

        //Main loop of game:
        while(guesses > 0){

            do{
                getUserInput();
            }while(!(validateInput(guessString))); 

            splitFamilies();//will change set of masterList when larger group is found. Changes occur AFTER where Exception is thrown
            printDifficultyList();
        }
    }

    private void importWords(){ //Adds to masterList. Both readers closed when finished.


        try{
            while(br.readLine() != null){
                line = br.readLine();
                masterList.add(line); 
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("An unexpected IO exception occurred. Check permissions of file!");
        }
    }


    private boolean validateLengthInput(String length){ //validation will change the set of masterList if valid.
        try{
            wordLengthInt = Integer.parseInt(length);
            if(!(wordLengthList.containsKey(wordLengthInt))){
                System.out.println("There are no words in the dictionary with this length.\n");
                return false;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("You must enter a number.\n");
            return false;
        }
        masterList = wordLengthList.get(wordLengthInt);
        return true;

    }


    private void splitFamilies(){ //will change set of masterList when larger group is found. Changes occur AFTER where Exception is thrown
        Iterator<String> it = masterList.iterator();
        int tempCount = 0;
        while(it.hasNext()){ 
            tempCount++;
            System.out.println("tempCount: " + tempCount);
            String i = it.next(); //Still throwing ConcurrentModification Exception
            if(i.contains(guessString)){
                contains.add(i);
            }else{
                doesNotContain.add(i);
            }
        }

        if(contains.size() > doesNotContain.size()){
            masterList = contains;
            correctGuess(); //does not use masterList
            profileWords();

        }
        else if(doesNotContain.size() > contains.size()){
            masterList = doesNotContain;
            incorrectGuess(); //does not use masterList
        }
        else{
            masterList = doesNotContain;
            incorrectGuess(); //does not use masterList
        }

    }



    private void printMasterList(){ //iterates through masterList - does not change it.
            for(String i : masterList){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }


    private void catalogLengths(){ //Iterates through masterList - does not change it.
        for(String i : masterList){
            if(i.length() != 0){
                if(!(wordLengthList.containsKey(i.length()))){
                    wordLengthList.put(i.length(), new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                wordLengthList.get(i.length()).add(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line the exception is thrown from is marked above in the code. Any method using `masterList` is also marked, any method included that does not use it, there is no comment against.

I did read some answers and some of them suggested using `Iterator` to avoid the exception. This is implemented above in `splitFamilies()`. The original code was as below:

```
private void splitFamilies(){ //will change set of masterList when larger group is found. Changes occur AFTER where Exception is thrown
        int tempCount = 0;
        for(String i : masterList){  //This line throws ConcurrentModificationException
            tempCount++;
            System.out.println("tempCount: " + tempCount);
            if(i.contains(guessString)){
                contains.add(i);
            }else{
                doesNotContain.add(i);
            }
        }
....continue as before
```

`tempCount` is always `2` when the exception is thrown.

Maybe I'm missing something really simple, but I've tried tracing this, and cannot find out why I'm getting this exception!

I've tried to remove everything irrelevant from the code, but if anyone really wants to view the full thing, I guess I could dump all my code in the question!

Comment: You're adding to `contains` and `doesNotContain` while iterating over `masterList`, which may be referencing the same.

Comment: You do `masterList = contains` or `masterList = doesNotContain`. Then you attempt to add to `contains` or `doesNotContain`. As shmosel said, `masterList` references the same list you are trying to modify. You *are* trying to modify a list while iterating over it, so 90% of those answers *do* apply, since `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown went attempting to **modify** a list while iterating over it, not just remove.

Comment: NB `while(br.readLine() != null)` and the following `readLine()` call are not correct. You will only see the even-numbered lines. It should be `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` without the following `readLine()`.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you!

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks for the reply Vince! I missed the fact that `masterList = contains` etc was actually just a reference! I looked at that as `masterList = new ArrayList<>(contains)` where the contents are copied over. Therefore, I didn't think I was accessing `masterList` whie iterating through it! I looked into what conditions throw `ConcurrentModificationException` but I just didn't think my circumstances fitted. Knowing what I know now, yes, the other answers apply! Haha

Comment: @EJP Thanks for pointing that out! I've not worked with the IO aspect of Java for a while, so I'm a little rusty with it. I'll change it to your suggestion and look into why it behaves that way to learn from it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that `masterList` is a reference to either `contains` or `doesNotContain` after a first split. When you iterate on `masterList`, you actually also iterate at the same time on that other list.

So, then you add items to the lists:

```
if(i.contains(guessString)){
    contains.add(i);
}else{
    doesNotContain.add(i);
}
```

Here you do not only add items to `contains` or `doesNotContain`, but also potentially to `masterList`, which leads to the `conccurentException`.

---

To solve your issue, just make a copy of your lists, instead of : `masterList = contains;`
do a copy with: `masterList = new ArrayList<>(contains);`

And the same for `doesNotContains`.

---

Another solution which comes to mind is to reset the two lists `contains` and `doesNotContains` for each split. Since you only use them in this method, and nowhere else, remove these two lists from your Class, and defines them as private variables inside `splitFamilies`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Swapped out the mentioned lines of code for your suggestion and all appears to be well! This has saved me a lot of trouble, thank you!